# Adding more than 1 column to ListView (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, listview, html-table, html

I am creating a webpage that is listing the names of places using ASP.NET. I am using a data source to read the data from a database file. The list view is displaying all the data in one column. What I am trying to do is add 7 rows of data and then as soon as the 7th row has been added, add another column, and then continue writing the data in the new created column. Here is my code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" DataSourceID="cwDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">VIEW STORE PAGE</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr runat="server" style="">
                                <td>COLUMN #</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Example of what the output should look like (The 'VIEW STORE PAGE' is just a link):

```
         COLUMN 1                      COLUMN 2
 A.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     H.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
 B.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     I.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
 C.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     J.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
 D.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     K.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
 E.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     L.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
 F.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     M.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
 G.ADDED    VIEW STORE PAGE     N.ADDED   VIEW STORE PAGE
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

```
<asp:DataList ID="cwDataList" runat="server" DataSourceID="cwDataSource" RepeatDirection=Vertical RepeatColumns=2 style="text-align: center">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <table style="width: 500px;">
        <tr style="">
          <td align="left" style="width: 250px; height: 18px">
              <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
          </td>
          <td align="left" style="width: 250px; height: 18px">
              <a href="#">VIEW STORE PAGE</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```